# 'Invalid use of void expression' passing arguments of functions

Tags: c++

This is a piece of my code that solves systems of differential equations.

```
Vector dydx(Neq);
void DiffEq(Vector x, Vector &dydx)
{
    dydx(0) = x(1);
    dydx(1) = -x(0);
}

double MidPoint(int n, Vector x)
{
    double h=H/n;
    Matrix z(n+1,n+1);
    z.fillRow(0,x);
    DiffEq(x, dydx);
    z.fillRow(1,AddVec(x, dydx*h));      //Error: Invalid use of void expression
    for (int j=1; j<n; j++)
    {
        DiffEq(z.getRow(j), dydx);
        z.fillRow(j+1, AddVec(z.getRow(j-1), dydx*h*2));     //error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
    }   
    DiffEq(z.getRow(n), dydx);
    return 0.5*AddVec(z.getRow(n), z.getRow(n-1), dydx*h);       //Error: Invalid use of void expression
}
```

The classes Vector and Matrix are custom. This is Vector

```
class Vector
{
    public:
    Vector(size_t size): vSize(size), vData(size){}
    int getSize(){return vSize;}
    double& operator()(size_t i){return vData[i];}
    double operator()(size_t i) const {return vData[i];}
    void operator+(double d)                        // These only overload the Vector + int operator
    {
        for (int i=0; i<vSize; i++) {vData[i]=vData[i]+d;}
    }

    void operator*(double d)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<vSize; i++) {vData[i]=vData[i]*d;}
    }


    size_t vSize;
    vector<double> vData;
};
```

With a function

```
Vector AddVec(Vector v1, Vector v2)
{
    Vector totVec(v1.getSize());
    for (int i=0; i<v1.getSize(); i++) {totVec(i) = v1(i) + v2(i);}
    return totVec;
}
```

And the same function for 3 vectors.

Now I realise that the error means that I'm passing void to some function, but I cannot figure out where things go wrong. When I try writing a test program, everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Sorry, dydx is a global vector. I'll edit it in. There are also some constants I left out to try to make the question a bit shorter.

Comment: I don't think so. The declaration of Vector is in a header file that's included. I should probably show my full code:
http://pastebin.com/sanKD2XJ    <-- main program
http://pastebin.com/qdZeVRQg    <-- containers.h

Comment: The problem is your `operator+` and `operator*` return `void`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your operators return void

```
void operator+(double d)                        // These only overload the Vector + int 
{
    for (int i=0; i<vSize; i++) {vData[i]=vData[i]+d;}
}

void operator*(double d)
{
    for (int i=0; i<vSize; i++) {vData[i]=vData[i]*d;}
}
```

So when you call `AddVec(x, dydx*h)` it calls `AddVec(x, void)`

Comment: It usually always is :)

Answer (score 1):

You've overloaded operators that don't behave like the conventional ones, **don't do that!!!**  Doing that gives C++ a bad name.

```
        void operator*(double d)
            {
            for (int i=0; i<vSize; i++) {vData[i]=vData[i]*d;}
            }
```

This doesn't return anything, so you can't use it like this:

```
 z.fillRow(1,AddVec(x, dydx*h)); 
                       ^^^^^^
```

`operator*` should return a new object, not modify its left operand.  If you want to modify the left operand, use `operator*=` but you should still return something.

```
        Vector& operator*=(double d)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<vSize; i++)
                vData[i] *= d;
            return *this;
        }

        Vector operator*(double d)
        {
            Vector v(*this); 
            v *= d;
            return v;
        }
```

The `operator*` would be better as a non-member, and should take its argument by reference:

```
        Vector operator*(const Vector& v, double d)
        {
            Vector v2(v); 
            v2 *= d;
            return v2;
        }
```